# Cannot display GET method to modify and update data with formData

Tags: reactjs, multer, form-data

I am training with ReactJS and NodeJS and trying to update a form. The POST method works, I use Multer and formData but I have a problem with the PUT/GET method to modify the data. In fact, PUT works, I can modify the data unlike the GET which displays [object Object]. I don't know where it can come from. You can see a screenshoot and the code, I use Material UI. [image]

```
import useRequest from "../../../customHooks/useRequest";

const CreateCustomer = ({ className, ...rest }) => {   
const [name, setName] = useState("");   
const [description, setDescription] = useState("");   
const [chosePicture, setChosePicture] = useState([]);
const classes = useStyles();

  const handleChangeName = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);   };

  const handleChangeDescription = (e) => {
    setDescription(e.target.value);   };

  const { uuid } = useParams();

  const toasterSucc = () => {
    return (
      toast.success('Customer successfully created!', {
        position: "bottom-center",
        autoClose: 4000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined
      })
    );   };

  const toasterErr = (error) => {
    return (
      toast.error(`${error}`, {
        position: "bottom-center",
        autoClose: 4000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined
      })
    );   };

  const updateSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("cust_main_name", name);
    formData.append("cust_details", description);
    formData.append("avatar", chosePicture);
    console.log(chosePicture);
    try {
      await axios.put(`http://xxx/customers/${uuid}`, formData);
      toasterSucc();
    } catch (er) {
      er.response && toasterErr(er.response.data);
    }   };

  const { data } = useRequest("get", `http://xxx/customers/${uuid}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data[0]) {
      setName(data[0]);
      setDescription(data[0]);
      setChosePicture(data[0]);
    }   }, [data]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
          <Grid>
            <Paper className={classes.mainTable}>
              <form className={classes.editForm} encType="multipart/form-data" method="post" autoComplete="off">

                <input
                  className={classes.btnfile}
                  type="file"
                  id="file"
                  name="avatar"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                  setChosePicture(e.target.files[0]);
                  }}
                />

                <TextField
                  className={classes.inputField}
                  label="Name"
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  value={name}
                  onChange={handleChangeName}
                  placeholder="Enter a name"
                  variant="outlined"                    
                  fullWidth
                  InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,
                  }}
                />

                <TextField
                  className={classes.inputField}
                  label="Description"
                  type="text"
                  name="description"
                  value={description}
                  onChange={handleChangeDescription}
                  placeholder="Enter a description"
                  fullWidth
                  InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,
                  }}
                  variant="outlined"
                />
                
              </form>
            </Paper>
          </Grid>

          <div className={classes.btnContainer}>
            <Button onClick={updateSubmit} type="submit" className={classes.button}>Save</Button>
            <ToastContainer />
          </div>

    </Fragment>   ); };

export default CreateCustomer;
```

The code for useRequest :

```
const useRequest = (method, url, option) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribe = true;
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await Axios[method](url);
        if (isSubscribe) {
          setData(result.data);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        if (isSubscribe) {
          setError(err);
          setData([]);
        }
      }
    };

    if (isSubscribe) {
      fetchData();
    }

    return () => {
      isSubscribe = false;
    };
  }, [url, method, option]);

  return { data, error };
};

export default useRequest;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning an `object` with properties `data` and `error`.

```
return { data, error };
```

It means that when you fetch it in client side, you will fetch object with both sub-objects. You should `console.log(data )` after fetching it and check the result.

```
const { data } = useRequest("get", `http://xxx/customers/${uuid}`)
```

You should extract only `data` sub-object and it will probably have `name` and `description` properties.

Comment: I finally solved the problem, thanks for the tips. This is the code : 

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data[0]) {
      const { cust_main_name, cust_details, path } = data[0]
      setName(cust_main_name);
      setDescription(cust_details);     
      setImage(path)
    }
  }, [data]);

Comment: I am glad you solved your problem. Consider also approving my answer if it helped you.